# Using IndexOf results to reference a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax

I am using two "indexOf" functions to find the row and then the column of the data I want to replace.  Code is as follows:

```
var timeIndex = lookupTime.indexOf(apptTime)+4;
var terrIndex = lookupTerr.indexOf(apptTerr)+1;

var overrideStart = masterAvail.getRange(terrIndex,timeIndex).getValue;
```

However, the "var OverrideStart" gives me the result of: function () { [native code] }

Please help!

Comment: getValue should be written getValue()

Comment: Oh geez, thank you.